# I don't know how to switch screens without using buttons in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, screen

I'm trying to make an app using Kotlin, but I'm curious to see how to switch screens through the navigation bar instead of buttons.

Comment: You can learn about this here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: Is this about Android?  Or some other platform?  It would help if you could add a relevant tag.